# How to give href for angularjs routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and Im currently trying to learn about ngRoute, but its not displaying anything

This is app.js config file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
  app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'index.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'bb.html',
            controller  : 'loginController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});
```

This is main index.html

```
    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    </head>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>

 <body ng-app="myApp">


<h1> User :{{user}}</h1>


<a href="#about">
    about
</a>

<h1>User :{{user}}</h1>

    </html></body>
</html>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

<script src="mainController.js"></script>
<script src="loginController.js"></script>
```

These are my controllers

```
//mainController.js
     app.controller('mainController',function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.user = "user";
    });
//loginController.js
  app.controller('loginController',function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.user = "user";

});
```

This is

When I click on about, it gives CANNOT GET /about, because it checks for node routes..How should I give the href for about?

Comment: try with this <a href="#about">

Comment: @DurgpalSingh http://localhost:8080/#about..but its not routing me to bb.html

Comment: why are you having multiple body tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `ng-app = "blog"` in your html and you have `angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);` in your js

Comment: thereafter, you need to add $scope.user inside the controller and then you will get the value in view.

Comment: Should i mention  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController"> ?

Comment: Yes...  And there should be only one <html></html>, one <head></head> and one <body></body> in any html page..